# jQuery Validate: change behaviour of error placement

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form with ratable options as radio buttons. What I am trying to achieve is the following:

- If an option has not been rated, I want the parent div "option-group" to have a red border. Once the option has been rated, I want the red border to disappear. So far, I have not found a solution.
- If the error message is visible and all required fields have been filled out, then I want the error message to disappear immediately.

Here comes the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/a05jrdau/9/

Here comes my code:

**HTML**

```
<form id="my-form" action="" method="post">
    <div id="msg-error"></div>
    <input type="text" id="myInput" name="myInput"/>
    <div class="option-con">
        <div class="option-label">
            Option 1
        </div>
        <div class="option-row">
            <input type="radio" name="radioOption1" value="1"/> 1
            <input type="radio" name="radioOption1" value="2"/> 2
            <input type="radio" name="radioOption1" value="3"/> 3
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="option-con">
        <div class="option-label">
            Option 2
        </div>
        <div class="option-row">
            <input type="radio" name="radioOption2" value="1"/> 1
            <input type="radio" name="radioOption2" value="2"/> 2
            <input type="radio" name="radioOption2" value="3"/> 3
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Test" />
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
.option-con {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.option-label, .option-row {
    float: left;
}

.option-row {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.error {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

**JS:**

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#my-form').validate({
                debug: true,
                rules: {
                    myInput: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    radioOption1: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    radioOption2: {
                        required: true
                    }
                },
                invalidHandler: function (event, validator) {
                    if (validator.errorList.length > 0) {
                        $('#msg-error').empty().html('Please fill in required fields.').show();

                    } else {
                        $('#msg-error').hide();
                    }
                },
                errorClass: "error"
            }
    )});
```

Comment: You don't have anything in your markup called `option-group`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to conditionally target the parent when the input element is a `radio`.  Use [the `highlight` and `unhighlight` callback functions](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#highlight) to over-ride the default behavior.

```
highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
    var target;
    if ($(element).is(':radio')) {
        target = $(element).parent('div');
    } else {
        target = $(element);
    };
    target.addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
},
unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
    var target;
    if ($(element).is(':radio')) {
        target = $(element).parent('div');
    } else {
        target = $(element);
    };
    target.addClass(validClass).removeClass(errorClass);
},
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/a05jrdau/10/**

Also note that, to suppress the error messages, you should put a `return false` inside of the `errorPlacement` callback function rather than leaving it empty.

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    return false;
},
```

You also do not need `errorClass: "error"` as `"error"` is the default setting.

---

**EDIT**:

Your error message is not clearing on a valid form because you're trying to do that within the `invalidHandler`, which only fires when the form is invalid AND you click the button.  `invalidHandler` can never clear the error message because it is never called when the form is valid or by any other triggering event.

You would use [the `showErrors` callback](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#showerrors) instead...

```
showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
    var msgerror = "All fields are required.";
    if (this.numberOfInvalids() > 0) {
        $('#msg-error').empty().html(msgerror).show();
    } else {
        $('#msg-error').hide();
    };
    this.defaultShowErrors();
},
```

**DEMO 2:  http://jsfiddle.net/a05jrdau/14/**